# Inserting node into binary tree using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a method for inserting nodes into a BST with the following structs:

```c
// node structure
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

// binary tree structure
struct BinaryTree {
    struct Node* root;
};
```

Originally I created this method for adding nodes to the tree:

```c
// add value to binary tree
void _AddNode(struct Node* node, int val) {
    if (node == NULL)
        *(&node) = CreateNode(val);
    else if (val <= node->val)
        _AddNode(node->left, val);
    else
        _AddNode(node->right, val);
}
void AddNode(struct BinaryTree* tree, int val) {
    _AddNode(tree->root, val);
}
```

Using this function to construct the tree, I get a `Segmentation fault: 11` error when I try to traverse, print, access data from the tree.

However, when I modified the function to pass in a double pointer and effectively do the same thing it worked:

```c
// add value to binary tree
void _AddNode(struct Node** node, int val) {
    if (*node == NULL)
        *node = CreateNode(val);
    else if (val <= (*node)->val)
        _AddNode(&(*node)->left, val);
    else
        _AddNode(&(*node)->right, val);
}
void AddNode(struct BinaryTree* tree, int val) {
    _AddNode(&tree->root, val);
}
```

Why does the latter work, but the former doesn't.

Comment: For all sorts of graphs, my common advice is to use pen and paper to solve the most common problems. Draw a tree on paper, using small squares for the nodes, and write the value inside the squares, and then use arrows for the pointers. "Rearrange" the tree by erasing arrows and redrawing them.

Comment: In the *"Originally I created"* code `*(&node)` isn't right. `node` (as a parameter) is declared local to the function and is equivalent to simply `node`.

Comment: They are not the same -- in the first case you can't change the pointer and in the 2nd you can.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the *"Originally I created"* and should have been more clear.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in C all symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like `_AddNode`) are *reserved*. See e.g. [this reserved identifier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) for details.

Comment: As for the crashing code (and to elaborate a little on Davids comments), in the `_AddNode` function the variable `node` is a *local* variable, and `&node` is a pointer to that local variable only. When you dereference `&node` you get back plain `node`. To emulate pass by reference in C you *must* pass pointers to the *variables*, which you do in the second snippet. Which for pointer variables means pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I modified the function to pass in a double pointer and effectively do the same thing it worked

Substantially the same thing, on fundamentally *different data*.  The `(&node)` in your original attempt gives you a pointer *to a local variable*.  When you dereference that and assign to the result, you are therefore modifying the local variable.  Such a modification is not visible in any way to the caller.

On the other hand if you pass (say) a suitable double pointer to your function, say `_AddNode(&(*node)->left, 42)`, then the value of the function parameter points to the same thing: the `(*node)->left` of the caller.  If you dereference that pointer and assign to the result then naturally that *is* visible to the caller.

> It seems that both the original and modified function are identical

Clearly, they are not lexically identical.  You seem to mean that they appear to you to be *equivalent*, but since the difference in behavior disproves such an equivalence, it stands to reason that the manifest differences in the two functions in fact produce different semantics.  The key thing that seems to have confused you is that in C, function arguments are always passed *by value*, so each function parameter starts with the *value* passed by the caller, but is not an alias for the caller's corresponding argument.  Parameters of pointer type are no exception.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, arguments that are passed to the function are local, so if I want to edit the value of a pointer I'd need to pass in the reference to that pointer (just like you would for a variable). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @JayMody, that's it exactly.  And you seem now to have grasped a point that causes many people trouble: pointers are just another data type, and pointer values are just values of that type, thoroughly analogous in that sense to `42` as a value of type `int`.